Formula for Sum of Numbers with Consecutive Digits

Let's say we have a number $n$ that consists of $b$ digits, all of which are the same digit $x$.
Then we have another number $m$ that has $b - 1$ digits, also all the same digit $x$.

How would you express the sum of $n$ and $m$ in terms of $b$ and $x$ ?.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you know how to express $n$ by itself in terms of $b$ and $x$? Hint: it's a geometric series.

"Consecutive Digits" suggests a number like $12345$ or $789$.  I think you just mean "numbers written with a single digit".

Note that $11111=\frac 19(10^5-1)$  You can use that to represent $n$ and $m$

What happens when you manually experiment, trying specific examples, looking for a pattern in the data?

We're essentially asking to find the digital representation of a sum in some base, so we'll go over the steps.
Let's say you're working on a base $B>1$ number system (if $B=1$ then every number is just a string of $1$'s). If $n = \underbrace{xx\dots x}_{b \text{ times}}$ and $m = \underbrace{xx\dots x}_{b-1 \text{ times}}$ (and thus $0\le x <B$) then
$$
n = \sum_{i=1}^{b}x B^{i-1},\quad m = \sum_{i=1}^{b-1}x B^{i-1}
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
n + m = \sum_{i=1}^{b}x B^{i-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{b-1}x B^{i-1} = x B^{b-1} +  \sum_{i=1}^{b-1}2x B^{i-1}
\end{align*}
Now, if we want to write the number in base $B$ then each digit in its representation must be between $0$ and $B-1$, but $2x$ might be bigger than $B-1$. We can solve this using Euclidean division.
Let $\color{blue}{2x} = \color{blue}{qB + r}$ with $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le r <B$. Since $x<B$ then $qB = 2x-r < 2B$ then $q \in \{0,1\}$. So as long as $B>1$ both $q,r$ are valid digits in the base $B$ representation. We get
$$
n+m = x B^{b-1} +  \sum_{i=1}^{b-1}\left(\color{blue}{qB + r}\right) B^{i-1}  = \left(x+q\right) B^{b-1} + \left(\sum_{i=2}^{b-1} (q+r)B^{i-1} \right) + r B^0 
$$
Notice that $q+r<B$ is always satisfied. The only option where it wouldn't is if $r =B-1$ and $q=1$, but then $2x = qB+r = 2B-1$ which is impossible since $2x$ is even and $2B-1$ is odd.
We again consider if $x+q<B$ or not to make it a valid digit.
To solve this we use the same trick. Writing $x+q = sB+t$ with $0\le t< B$ and $sB = x+q-t < B+1$ so $s \in \{0,1\}$ as well. Putting it all together we get
$$
n+m = sB^b + tB^{b-1} + \left(\sum_{i=2}^{b-1} (q+r)B^{i-1} \right) + r B^0 
$$
Now we just need to write $s,t,q,r$ in terms of $x,B$ to finish the problem. Since $2x = qB+r$ we get
$$
\frac{2x}{B} = q + \frac{r}{B} \implies \left\lfloor \frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor = q  \implies 2x - \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor B = r
$$
and similarly, since $x+q = x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor = sB+t$ we get
$$
s = \left\lfloor \frac1{B}\left( x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor\right)\right\rfloor \implies t = x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor \frac1{B}\left( x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor\right)\right\rfloor B
$$
Resulting in
\begin{align*}
n+m &= \color{purple}{ \left\lfloor \frac1{B}\left( x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor\right)\right\rfloor} B^b + \left(\color{purple}{x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor \frac1{B}\left( x + \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor\right)\right\rfloor B} \right) B^{b-1}\\
& \quad + \left[\sum_{i=2}^{b-1} \left(\color{purple}{2x +\left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor(1- B)}\right)B^{i-1} \right] + r\left(\color{purple}{2x - \left\lfloor\frac{2x}{B} \right\rfloor B }\right) B^0
\end{align*}
where the digits are colored in $\color{purple}{\text{purple}}$. For the ordinary base $10$ case just substitute $B=10$.

Some immediate conclusions from the above are:

Any such sum will have at most $4$ distinct digits, and it's reached by some. For example $999+99$ in base $10$.
There's always a string of at least $b-2$ consecutive digits.


This is way too complicated. Ross Millikan provided a more elegant solution in his comment.

@Saša, my answer and Ross' are answers to different things. I understood that OP wanted the digits of the sum, which is not the same as just calculating the sum. Ross' answer gives the sum, but if you want the digits you require more work.
